# Filter HTML Content of Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am using the Marketpress plugin. I want to modify `single_order_funct()` function HTML content in it. I want to make changes so that, when it is updated, I don't lose them.

```
<?php
 class PluginClass{
   function single_order_funct() {
?>
    <h1>test</h1>
<?php
  }

  function orders_funct() {
    if (isset($_GET['order_id'])) {
      $this->single_order_funct();
      return;
     }
  }
```

Whenever `single_order_funct()` function is called, I want to modify the HTML content it returns. How can I do it with `remove_action()` and `add_action()` or is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. In WordPress terms, the code is not prepared for that. It should have `add_action()` or `do_action()` defined/declared somewhere for `remove_action()` and `add_action()` (respectively) to be useful.

The best bet is to ask the developer to add a **hook** (a [*filter hook*](http://ottopress.com/2011/actions-and-filters-are-not-the-same-thing/) in this case) in the `single_order_funct` method.

Comment: Or maybe you're not showing the whole relevant code. How is the class instantiated?